# Documentation of a class property is returned as null when accessed from other projects

Tags: c#, web-services, documentation

I am trying to create Web API documentation (which is a part of web-service) for our project. When I try to read the ResourceModal of an Object (http://localhost:56258/Help/ResourceModel?modelName=LoginInfo) that resides in the same project it gives me the Property Documentation correctly.

```
namespace SmartTouch.CRM.WebService.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// LoginInfo
    /// </summary>
    public class LoginInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Email that is used to login to SmartTouch Web Application
        /// </summary>
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        ///  Password that is used to login to SmartTouch Web Application
        /// </summary>
        public string Password { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Client ID that is provided by SmartTouch Administrator
        /// </summary>
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    }  
}
```

[image]
But, when i try to read the ResourceModal of another Object which resides in another project then the Description is being returned as null though I have generated the XMLDocumentation file. Any help?